# And/Or in Access and Counting Multiple Fields

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am trying to get a total of the number of promotions before 2015 from the following table [image: Table]

I have used the following code

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS [Total Promotions Before 2015] FROM [Employment History] 
WHERE IIF([Date of 1st Promotion]<#1/1/2015#,1,0)
OR  IIF([Date of 2nd Promotion]<#1/1/2015#,1,0)
OR  IIF([Date of 3rd Promotion]<#1/1/2015#,1,0)
OR  IIF([Date of 4th Promotion]<#1/1/2015#,1,0)
OR  IIF([Date of 5th Promotion]<#1/1/2015#,1,0)
;
```

However this only gives me the number of individuals with promotions before 2015, rather than the number of promotions themselves.
Is there a way to make this more like 
+1 to count if promotion in 1st year
and +1 if in 2nd year etc

Comment: consider giving an example of the output you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS [Total Promotions Before 2015]
FROM [Employment History] 
WHERE [Date of 1st Promotion] < #1/1/2015# OR
      [Date of 2nd Promotion] < #1/1/2015# OR
      [Date of 3rd Promotion] < #1/1/2015# OR
      [Date of 4th Promotion] < #1/1/2015# OR
      [Date of 5th Promotion] < #1/1/2015#;
```

But I think you really want:

```
SELECT SUM(IIF([Date of 1st Promotion] < #1/1/2015#, 1, 0)) +
       SUM(IIF([Date of 2nd Promotion] < #1/1/2015#, 1, 0)) +
       SUM(IIF([Date of 3rd Promotion] < #1/1/2015#, 1, 0)) +
       SUM(IIF([Date of 4th Promotion] < #1/1/2015#, 1, 0)) +
       SUM(IIF([Date of 5th Promotion] < #1/1/2015#, 1, 0))
FROM [Employment History] ;
```